# Modifying code to suit different configurations in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, ant, android-gradle-plugin

I have different configurations for my Android project (e.g. google, amazon). Gradle allows generating BuildConfig parameters, that can be checked at runtime, but this isn't what I am really after. I want to have a particular code (method, class, etc) *to be present or absent* (not just bypassed) in the project, depending on configuration.

This is how I implement that in Eclipse. I have a folder in an Eclipse project (named e.g. *platform-specific*), *not included* in BuildPath as well as several Ant scripts (make-google, make-amazon), that copy relevant files from platform-specific folder to src folder and delete irrelevant files from src folder.

Since Eclipse provides an Ant window to view all scripts, I can run a particular script and reconfigure the project to suit chosen configuration.

Is there a way to do that in Android Studio? I know that Gradle allows running and even importing an Ant script, but it isn't a convenient as with 'true' Ant, and I can't find a way to choose a script to run. Maybe Gradle provides its own way to do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: CommonsWare: This doesn't allow code modification (as I mentioned)

Comment: Sure it does. Put the code needed specifically for the particular configuration in the source set for that configuration's flavor. Put all the common elements in `main`.

Comment: See, what I can do about that. At the moment it looks really stiff to me. For two flavours it will work, but if I have say 3 flavours, module 1 appears in flavours 1 and 2, module 2 in flavours 1 and 3, will it mean replicating those modules in each folder? So, every time I modify a code a such a module, I need to replicate the modification in another folder. Such a shame that Java doesn't offer a preprocessor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For two flavours it will work, but if I have say 3 flavours, module 1 appears in flavours 1 and 2, module 2 in flavours 1 and 3, will it mean replicating those modules in each folder? So, every time I modify a code a such a module, I need to replicate the modification in another folder.

Not if you organize your code.

You appear to be using "modules" generically. Android Studio has a specific definition of that term (what Gradle refers to as sub-projects). And you can leverage those to help your cause.

Suppose that you create `google`, `amazon`, and `yandex` product flavors. Then:

- Any code that is common to all three goes in `src/main/`.
- Any code that is unique to a single flavor goes in that flavor's source set (e.g., `src/yandex/`).
- Any code that is shared by two flavors goes into a library module that is added to the appropriate flavors using flavor-specific dependencies (e.g., `yandexCompile` and `amazonCompile`).

In all cases, there is one copy of your code. Whether it can go in the application module (e.g., `app/`) or goes into a library module depends on which flavors need that code. For a scenario like this, dependency injection will help you manage what code then gets wired together for each flavor.

Comment: It will be helpful,  if you suggest a sample (open source) project that uses this approach.

Comment: @cyanide: If by "this approach" you mean "product flavors", searching `"build.gradle" productFlavors"` on Google turns up lots of pages, including [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) (though note that as of Android Studio 3.0, all product flavors need to be part of a `flavorDimension`). If by "this approach", you mean what I refer to in the third bullet of my answer, I'll be fairly surprised if any open source project uses it.